# How to publish an app the need a lot of users to be good

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, publish

I am making an app that allows users to post and view different topics.This app is like Pinterest.

My question is, When i first release the app, the first 100 people that download it, will see very little posts, and the user will most likely delete it. How do i launch the app so there are a lot of posts and activity going on so the users are happy?

Comment: Create some seed content yourself or pay people to do it. If you do it yourself, create mechanisms that make it easier for you to create and post as a bunch of different users. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmeDzx4SUME&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a marketing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to have your app full of spam and fake posts which will definitely make your users want to leave, you will have to market your app much like any other app. Tell your friends, family, get into a few forums and let people know, use twitter or other social media.

It's just marketing. Build up a following before you release.

**Edit**

Although if what you mean is how can you get users to post more, you can use methods that allow people to post from using other services e.g, twitter, tumblr, instagram.